# get value of variable and insert to db

Tags: php, mysql

```
     <?php
     **$sum**=$num1 + num2;
      ?>
```

I wanted to insert the value of the variable to my db.

EXAMPLE:

```
    <?php 
        if (!empty(isset($_POST["submit_n"])))
        {
          $project_name = $_POST["project_name"];
         $num1 = $_POST["num1"];
          $num2 = $_POST["num2"];
          **$result= $sum;**

           $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ongoing_project(project_name,num1,num2,result) VALUES ('$project_name','$num1','$num2','$result')";
           $res = $con->query($sql);
           }
      ?>
```

The query works when I still did not include the 'result' part.

Hoping for your understanding.
Still a newbie here.

Comment: first of all: that's not your real problem. the real problem is: your code is wide open to **SQL Injection** - imagine someone posting a "no_of_OP" as `'; DROP TABLE tbl_ongoing_project; --` - use **parameterized statements** to protect yourself against injection *and*, just as a side effect, solve most problems you will probably have when working with databases

Comment: Can var dump the $sum ?

Comment: I already worked it out. Thank you for the information. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your `$sum` is having no value (even a 0). I see an error there, look at that `num2`. You're missing a `$`.

- Have you declared each variable a default value, like for example `$num1 = 0;`?

If not, you should declare first so if a case happens that you'll get a null or unknown value, you still have the default value. Handle the possible scenarios to avoid getting undesired values.

You can also use `var_dump($your_variable);` to check the information of your variable or even your query.

For the structure of your codes, you can read about [SQL Injection](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sql-injection.htm) here.

Comment: Oh, I still haven't learned that part .. It worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

> Note : always remember one thing, if you declare variables you should initialized them before you use them.
> Then you can avoid unnecessary errors.
>
> A variable starts with the $ sign, followed by the name of the
> variable
>
> When receive any global variable like $_POST or any array you should check yourself by using var_dump($_POST);  or print_r($_POST); then you could have seen the variable or array whether content your desire value or not.
> variable can not delivery output in single quote. Hope you are clear about it.If you have any more query regarding it you could ask feel free. thanks

- your Mistake : Not initialized variable;
- `num2` instead of $num2
- `('$project_name','$num1','$num2','$result')`; instead of `VALUES ('".$project_name."','".$num1."','".$num2."','".$result."')`

$num1 = $num2 = $result = "";

```
if (!empty(isset($_POST["submit_n"]))) {
   $project_name = $_POST["project_name"];
   $num1 = $_POST["num1"];
   $num2 = $_POST["num2"];
   $result = ($num1+$num2);
   $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ongoing_project(project_name,num1,num2,result) VALUES ('".$project_name."','".$num1."','".$num2."','".$result."')";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it working now because of all the answers I received here.